# use double asterisk operator in django templates

Tags: python, django

I'd like to provide some extra templates for my base template to include, just like the following code:

*views*:

```
def my_view(request):
    extra_templates=[
        {'path': 'dashboard/timewindow.html'},
        {'path': 'dashboard/search_box.html'},
    ]
    context = {'extras': extra_templates}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/base.html', context)
```

*base.html*

```
{% for extra_template in extras %}
  {% include extra_template.path %}
{% endfor %}
```

I think this can be more powerful, if I can also provide some keyword arguments and use them as context when rendering the extra templates, but I couldn't do it, the following code **doesn't work**:

*views*:

```
def my_view(request):
    extra_templates=[
        {'path': 'dashboard/timewindow.html', 'context': {'var': 23}},
        {'path': 'dashboard/search_box.html'},
    ]
    context = {'extras': extra_templates}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/base.html', context)
```

*base.html*

```
{% for extra_template in extras %}
  {% include extra_template.path with extra_template.context %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I could use something like the `**` operator inside a django template, that would allow some very awesome code reusage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You can not use double asterisks in `include` tag. `include` tag's `with` parameter only understands `foo=1` or `1 as foo` notations.

So, you have three options:

1) Included template will have all variables available from top level template. Main con: `timewindow.html` and `search_box.html` can't have same variable with different values.

```python
def my_view(request):
    extra_templates=[
        {'path': 'dashboard/timewindow.html'},
        {'path': 'dashboard/search_box.html'},
    ]
    context = {'extras': extra_templates, 'var': 23}
    return render(request, 'dashboard/base.html', context)
```

2) Use prefix

```html
{# parent template #}
{% for extra_template in extras %}
    {% include extra_template.path with extra=extra_template.context %}
{% endfor %}

{# included template #}
{{ extra.var }}
```

3) Write custom template tag and expand context by yourself